# Software to remote access and control target device

Tags: manual-testing, embedded

I have encountered such a problem not only at my current job, but also before. it's about manual testing the software on various embedded devices in a remote way.

Maybe you know if there is any software to automate this process, with these common requirements:

- web to provide information of devices list with installed version and hardware information
- web based interface to lock device for a specific user to test or flash new software
- web int. to ssh to target device
- web int. to view video of device on some external camera, with audio
- interacting with device by speach or touch screen, poweroff, reset device
- flash device with new software by ssh, serial or some other
- target device is linux based OS but can be any Android, Tizen or custom build dist

I know that some of this requirements cannot be met without installing some software on the target device (ex to handle touch screen) but this cannot be huge server consuming too much device resources, just minimal solution.

In work we always used worker device (some PC) connected to target (tested device) by serial and ethernet. Worker with camera and speaker accessed remotely by users to control and flash the device. This setup is general for all devices like TV, HMI devices, ... .

The real issue is that we always needed to write software (web+backend) to handle this setup which was in 80% exactly the same in functionality. I'm wondering and want to ask is there any software with UI and general functionality already programmed so we can just add backend implementation for handling our devices?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Hopefully, someone has an answer, but I can already see people wanting to close this question. I think due to a lot of us are unfamiliar with embedded device software testing, as a lot of this community really focuses on desktop, web, mobile software apps. This may be a situation where you have to create your own tooling.

Comment: I have zero experience with embedded software, but a bit of searching found a few links you may find of interest/value: https://www.rapitasystems.com/embedded-software-testing-tools (site is dedicated to its own tools), https://www.sam-solutions.com/blog/five-best-tools-to-improve-embedded-software-testing/, https://www.embedded.com/effective-test-strategies-for-reducing-embedded-software-development-costs/ (more of a general article on principles)

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools available in the market that can help you automate the testing process for remote devices. Here are a few options that you can explore:

1. Testdroid: Testdroid is a cloud-based mobile testing platform that provides access to real mobile devices, including Android and iOS devices. It provides a web interface that allows users to manage the devices, perform manual and automated tests, and view test reports. Testdroid supports a variety of test automation frameworks, including Appium, Espresso, and Robotium.
2. BrowserStack: BrowserStack is a cloud-based testing platform that provides access to a wide range of real mobile devices, including Android, iOS, and Windows Phone devices. It provides a web interface that allows users to manage the devices, perform manual and automated tests, and view test reports. BrowserStack supports a variety of test automation frameworks, including Selenium and Appium.
3. Sauce Labs: Sauce Labs is a cloud-based testing platform that provides access to real mobile devices, including Android and iOS devices. It provides a web interface that allows users to manage the devices, perform manual and automated tests, and view test reports. Sauce Labs supports a variety of test automation frameworks, including Selenium and Appium.
4. Firebase Test Lab: Firebase Test Lab is a cloud-based testing platform that provides access to real Android and iOS devices. It provides a web interface that allows users to manage the devices, perform manual and automated tests, and view test reports. Firebase Test Lab supports a variety of test automation frameworks, including Espresso and Robolectric.

These tools can help you automate the testing process for remote devices, and they provide a web interface that allows you to manage the devices, perform manual and automated tests, and view test reports. You can choose the tool that best suits your needs and requirements.